# How to println NSTimeInterval in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, println, nstimeinterval

I want to print `elapsedTime` using a println or NSLog statement. How to convert `NSTimeInterval elapsedTime` to String to print it?

```
t_start = NSDate()
var elapsedTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(t_start)
println("in applicationDidEnterBackground, elapsedTime = " + elapsedTime)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error:

`NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(t_start)` should be `NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(t_start)`.

Then use String Interpolation in the println statement.

Here is a corrected version:

```
let t_start = NSDate()
let elapsedTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(t_start)
println("in applicationDidEnterBackground, elapsedTime =\(elapsedTime)")
```

Output:

> "in applicationDidEnterBackground, elapsedTime =0.00790297985076904"

With fewer decimal points use String format:

```
println(String(format: "in applicationDidEnterBackground, elapsedTime =: %.3f sec", elapsedTime))
```

Output

> in applicationDidEnterBackground, elapsedTime =: 0.008 sec

Comment: thank you that worked, will mark as answer in 2 mins when SO allows

Answer (score 1):

You can use elapsedTime.description or String Interpolation

```
"\(elapsedTime)"
```